# How to write multiple data frames to CSV preceded by a key value in R

Tags: r, csv

I have multiple data frames with the following format:

```
      col1  col2  col3  col4
row1    1    0     1      1
row2    0    1     1      0
row3    1    1     0      1
```

where row# are rownames and col# are column names.

Each of the frames I have represent values related to a specific product record in my data base. I need to add the record id before each data frame in a csv file to be like this

```
               col1  col2  col3  col4
prod_id1 row1    1    0     1      1
prod_id1 row2    0    1     1      0
prod_id1 row3    1    1     0      1
prod_id2 row1    1    0     1      1
prod_id2 row2    0    1     1      0
prod_id2 row3    1    1     0      1
```

How can I do this in R? I tried the following:

```
write.table(c("prod_id1",df1), "test.csv", col.names=TRUE, sep=",")
write.table(c("prod_id2",df2), "test.csv", col.names=FALSE, sep=",", append=TRUE)
```

But it did not work. The rows names were erased and one of the columns in the df were erased as well. Also, the number or rows can change with each product and is known at run time.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: I'd just create two new columns.. one for the row names, one for product id (something like `df_new <- data.frame(product_id = "prod_id1", rows = rownames(df), df)`. Then just `rbind` all your data frames together. Finally, use `write.csv(df_total, "test.csv", quote=F, row.names=F)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `names` argument of `data.frame` to change the row names at the time you are writing the csv.

```
df1 <- data.frame(x = 1:8,   y = 11:18, z = 21:28)
df2 <- data.frame(x = 31:38, y = 41:48, z = 51:58)

write.table(
  x = data.frame(df1, row.names = paste0('prod_id1',row.names(df1))),
  file = "test.csv",
  col.names = TRUE,
  sep=",")

write.table(
  x = data.frame(df2, row.names = paste0('prod_id2',row.names(df2))),
  file = "test.csv",
  col.names = TRUE,
  sep=",",
  append = T)
```

Comment: This code concatenated the product_id to the row names in the df (i.e. the cell now contains 'prod_id1row1'). It did not put it in a separate column :(

Comment: Row names are always the first thing output by `write`. You could use `data.frame(prod = 'prod_id1', RN = row.names(df1) , df1)` and set `row.names = F` on `write`.